# PHP fopen(): Filename cannot be empty cause by getRealPath return false

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing Laravel project on Windows 10 locally using Laragon

PHP version: 7.1.8 64bit NTS

related php.ini that I know is

post_max_size = 8M

file_uploads = On

---

Source code:

```
// if no image uploaded
if (!$request->hasFile('profile_picture')) 
throw new \Exception("No image found");

// get uploaded image
$image = $request->file('profile_picture');

// store to storage/app/users/
Storage::putFileAs('users', $image ,auth()->id());
```

[image]

In my opinion, this is server configuration issue, probably problem on php.ini,

but I'm not familiar with server configuration, and there is not so many topics online related with this issue.

I know the problem cause, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: thanks for fast reply, for sure I had checked, the authentication is pass and id return 1 (user id)

Comment: for those down vote this question, may I know why?

Comment: maybe a downvote for the 'Critic' badge

Comment: @MiSAKACHi can you explain? I'm not familiar with stackoverflow's rule

Comment: Look here... https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: ermmmm..... good reason

Comment: I voted you up, thanks for the question! Now you are out of negative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that the user that runs your Web Server Process User has RW (Read/Write) access to Windows TEMP Directory? If no, you will definitely fail!

> A possible fix for this is to set the PHP TEMP Dir to a readable/writeable location.

On your `php.ini` set this directive.

`upload_tmp_dir` = 'PATH'

Make sure that the 'PATH' exists and your Web Server Process User has read/write access to it.

Web Server Process User is the account that is used by your web server to run the service. You can check this on the Task Manager.

Comment: Ya, you answer give me inspiration on how to solve it. Thanks you

Comment: Thanks, answer helped. We had this problem with Internet Information Services (IIS) for Windows® Server. And only thing needed was - permission for C:\Windows\temp because it is set as upload_tmp_dir in php.ini for php7. Thanks!

Comment: It's bizarre that PHP can write uploaded files to the C:\Windows\Temp directory, but cannot run `realpath` on it. Unless I am mistaken and the files are stored by IIS, but even then, isn't it the same user for IIS that runs PHP? In any case, changing the upload directory is was easier for local development.

Answer (score 3):

After 2 days, I finally figured out why. Last time, I used PHP-TS (Thread Safe) version to develop this application and it worked normally.

By now, I'm using PHP-NTS (Non Thread Safe) version and, after testing, I was able to confirm that this issue was caused by different file info result of NTS & TS

For PHP 7.1.7 64bit TS
[image: TS]

For PHP 7.1.8 64bit NTS
[image: NTS]

So by now we can know that bug occurs on temp folder setting,

For NTS version, temp folder on C:\Windows\Temp,

No permission of this folder cause PHP can't read the realPath (I guess), realPath return false

For TS version, temp folder on C:\Users\YQuan\AppData\Local\Temp,

Allow to access, realPath readable

#### Solution

1. Change permission to folder effected

   I won't using this method because too messy to change permission on Windows system
2. set upload_tmp_dir in php.ini to "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp", then restart server

   this method is easier.

Comment: Thanks for having me a lot of time, I was switching from 7.2 TS to 7.1-nts for testing and forgot to change it back.