# Laravel 5.4 fopen(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload image in laravel 5.4
Here's the code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->image->isValid()) {
        $image = $request->image;

        $image_name = bcrypt($image->getClientOriginalName());

        Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('images', $image, $image_name . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension());

        $article->image($image_name);
    }
```

> in FilesystemAdapter.php (line 146)

I checked the FileSystemAdapter.php and saw that the problem is in this line:

```
$stream = fopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r+');
```

When I var dump the $file variable it returns the correct info, but when I `var_dump($file->getRealPath();` it says `bool(false)` and I can't upload the image

Comment: Try to change `$image = $request->image;` to `$image = $request->file('image');`

Comment: @Laerte the result is the same

Comment: It works fine with me. What does the `image` method do?

Comment: It works just fine to me also. Do you getting any errors?

Comment: Is this your first time working with file uploads? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45548530/6294600

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We had this problem with Internet Information Services (IIS) for Windows® Server. And only thing needed was - permission for `C:\Windows\temp` because it is set as `upload_tmp_dir` in `php.ini` for php7.

Comment: your answer helped me to found out what is my problem thanks

Comment: you saved my life for second time in windows 2012 R2 that hosted my laravel app

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, how you changed the permissions?

Comment: add `IIS_IUSRS` user to the window's temp folder. thanks! `[+1]`

Answer (score 10):

My case with Laragon 4.0.12 on Windows 10.

The problem was that upload_tmp_dir=... in my php.ini had not set needed permissions.

If this setting is commented the value should be the default windows temp directory (C:\Windows\Temp you can check your permissions for it).

The solution - I changed it to:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Users\{my_user}\AppData\Local\Temp"
```

in order to avoid messing up with changing permissions.

Restart the server after the change to take effect.

Another settings in php.ini to consider:

```
upload_max_filesize = 
max_file_uploads =
```

Also following php extensions are needed to be enabled: exif, gd2

Comment: Just opening `C:\Windows\Temp` on File Explorer and accepting the permission prompt did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

My case was:

The target folder did not exist there. And I created it. So the error is gone.

laravel admin drive is defined here:

```
Config/admin.php
```

You can define it in `public` folder, for example : `upload` folder in `public`.

My target folder (`images`) should be created in `/uploads/` not in `public`

So I create `images` in `upload` and error is gone

Comment: @NicoHaase last night i was tired. So i edit this answer again