# fopen(): Filename cannot be empty - Laravel 5 IIS 7

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-upload, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

im facing this problem all day long, i already saw this question([Laravel 5.4 fopen(): Filename cannot be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619248/laravel-5-4-fopen-filename-cannot-be-empty)) and nothing...

I already edit permission on my `C:\Windows\Temp` full control to my `IISR_IUSERS` i'm using NTS PHP version on my IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2.

on my Laravel code i'm doing this:

```
$input['picture_url'] = $request->file($fileInForm)->store('uploads');
```

on my development enviroment it's a Macosx And i was doing this to save the image to my uploads folder that i configure like this:

```
    /*My code to upload imagem on MACOSX dev enviroment*/

    $input = array();

    $fileInForm = 'picture_url';

    if ($request->hasFile($fileInForm)) {
    $file = $request->file($fileInForm);
    if ($file->isValid()) 
    {
        var_dump($request->file('default_picture_url')->path());
        die();

        // Filename is hashed filename + part of timestamp
        $hashedName = hash_file('md5', $file->pathName());
        //$timestamp = (microtime() * 1000000);

        $newFilename = $hashedName . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

       Storage::disk('uploads')->put($newFilename, file_get_contents($file));

       $input['default_picture_url'] = '/uploads/'.$newFilename;
    }
    }

/*My filesystems.php*/
'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path().'/uploads' 
        ],
```

And I already modified `php.ini` `upload_tmp_dir` to `C:\Windows\Temp` or `C:/Windows/Temp`

can anyone help me with this please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the same problem in PHP 7.3 and IIS. I will explain below how I resolved this issue.

Step 1: I have given full permission (any user can access) to C:\Windows\Temp.

Step 2: Edit php.ini file `upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Windows\Temp"`, `sys_temp_dir = "C:\Windows\Temp"`

Step 3: Enable extension `extension=fileinfo` in php.ini and restart the server.

Initially I used `C:\Windows\Temp` later I have created separate temp folder and used that folder `C:\inetpub\www\temp`.

Comment: sorry to take so long to come here and  thank you properly for your answer!